# How can the client connect to the server when the server is in a busy loop?

Tags: java, sockets

Server looks like this:

```
public class Server {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    server.start(5006);
}

private void start(int port) {
    try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));) {
        String line;
        while (true) {
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println("line = " + line);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The client looks like this:

```
public class Client {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client client = new Client();
    client.start("localhost", 5006);
}

private void start(String localhost, int port) {
    Random random = new Random();
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(localhost, port);
         BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
        while (true) {
            int i = random.nextInt();
            bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(i));
            bufferedWriter.newLine();
            System.out.println("i = " + i);

            //sleep(bufferedWriter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sleep(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter) throws Exception{
        //bufferedWriter.flush(); //Has to enabled if the wait below is to work
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
}
```

**Context:**

As is evident from the code, the server is single threaded. It accepts a connection from the client and goes into a busy loop processing data from the client socket. The server is intentionally handicapped.

Running one instance of the client program works as intended. The client ends random integers and the same are printed on the server's console.

**Questions:**

1) While one instance of the client is still running, spin up another instance of the client program.

- How is this instance of the client able to connect to the server when the server is still in the busy loop (while(true))?
  The client goes so far as to fill up the buffered writer and then just hangs; waiting for the server to consume the stream.

2) In the client program, uncomment the 'sleep' method and re-run.

- The client program hangs. The server does not receive anything. Why? I just want to write to the buffer every 3 seconds. Nonsensical but let's suppose it is a sane thing to do for arguments sake. I also put in the sleep after we send the new line to the server just to make sure the server prints its input.
- If you uncomment the flush in the sleep method, it starts working again. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this instance of the client able to connect to the server when the server is still in the busy loop (`while(true)`)? The client goes so far as to fill up the buffered writer and then just hangs; waiting for the server to consume the stream.

Because of the listen backlog queue. The operating system completes the inbound connection and places it on the backlog queue. `accept()` blocks while the backlog queue is empty and then removes the first connection from it. The client's connect operation is complete *before* the corresponding `accept()` is called, and because the client now has a connection it can now write a certain amount of data to it.

> 2) In the client program, uncomment the 'sleep' method and re-run. The client program hangs.

It sleeps for three seconds. It doesn't 'hang'. Because of the much slower output, it takes much (*much*) longer for the `BufferedWriter`'s buffer to fill and output to be flushed to the server.

> The server does not receive anything. Why?

Because you haven't flushed the buffer.

> I just want to write to the buffer every 3 seconds. Nonsensical but let's suppose it is a sane thing to do for arguments sake. I also put in the sleep after we send the new line to the server just to make sure the server prints its input.
>
> If you uncomment the flush in the sleep method, it starts working again. Why?

See above.

Comment: Makes sense. I was not aware of the OS intervention. Thanks @EJP

Answer (score -1):

1) Two clients:

A. Client 1 steps:

- (As EJP said), Connection established on OS level and placed in backlog queue.
  Then it is waiting for ServerSocket to pick it and start reading from `clientSocket InputStream`
- Client 1 writes data to its `socket OutputStream` - server's reader reads data from `clientSocket InputStream`
  Server is busy, because infinite loop.

B. Client 2 steps:

- (As EJP said), Connection established on OS level and placed in backlog queue.
- By this code it will never be picked by `ServerSocket`. Server is indefinitely busy with indefinitely open Socket to Client 1.
- All data written from Client 2 stays in the buffer on Client 2 side.

*Note: Client 2 will never go beyond that point with current code even if Client 1 process be killed and connection from it to server be broken, server will end. There is no second `accept()` call to process request from Client 2*

2) `flush`

- when Client writes bytes to its `socket OutputStream` bytes goes to the buffer first not over network to the server.
- `flush` forces OutputStream to send whatever is in the buffer at this moment.
- Without `flush` data be send to the server when buffer is full.
- If you do not have `flush` somewhere in the code flow, server never receives anything. It keeps waiting for data indefinitely in current code. But all data stay in buffer at client side waiting for `flush` or buffer be full.

3)

> The client program hangs.

Assumption is not correct. Client program does not hang. It is running  and fill the buffer, but nothing sends to the server until buffer is full.

With or without `flush` it does not matter is there `sleep` or not.

"No sleep" - buffer fills very quickly. "sleep" buffer fills once per 3 sec. It just need a time to fill the buffer.

> If you uncomment the flush in the sleep method, it starts working again. Why?

Only server starts receiving data earlier, because client does not wait to fill the buffer to send data and flushes buffer after each write.

Comment: Voting is secret here, but I can see that you haven't answered the first question; your paragraph (2) is both poor English and full of *non sequiturs;*  and your paragraph (3) is incorrect and contrary to exactly what the OP is asking about in his first question.

Comment: Sorry for my English, but in the code there is no way to accept second call. So... your `client now has a connection` will never happen for second client.

Comment: You are mistaken. It *did* happen, and that's what he's asking about. Try it for yourself before you repeat that statement. See also the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I did that many times and I know how it works... where is a place to get a connection from second client? it can be done only when `ServerSocket.accept()` invoked. That code will end when `while (true) {` loop done. there is no "magic". To get second connection  `ServerSocket.accept()` must be called again.

Comment: You said "corresponding accept() is called" where is second "corresponding accept()"? No `accept` - no client Socket to work with. Second connection will be broken

Comment: The client's second connection succeeds immediately. It  does *not* 'wait until either Server completes its first request' etc. That's what he's asking about. Even though no 'corresponding' `accept()` has ever been called by the server. When the server exits, that connection will *then* be broken, but it does exist.

Comment: I didn't said that there wil be no second connection. But second request will never be processed by that code.

Comment: You still haven't answered the actual question. And you can see the confusion your poorly written answer has caused. I suggest you clarify it. Extensively.

Comment: OK I clarified all I can

Comment: @Vadim You are right when you say the server is no position to call the accept method second time around. That was intentional. Your answer and EJP's answer makes sense. Thank you both!